# Can we get Search Queries details from Google Webmaster tools API?

Tags: google-search-console

I just want to know can we get the Search Queries details from Google Webmaster tools API?

Answer (score 2):

Not via the API, but you can use the scripts referred to on http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/download-search-queries-data-using.html to get the same data.

Comment: Note that this script uses ClientLogin for authentication which will be shut down on April 20, 2015.