# How to get query details FROM webmasters tools api

Tags: php, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

the new api webmasters tools is not mentioned how to get the details of queries.

Here is my code to get the queries, but I dont know how to get for each query the details :

```
$client->setAccessToken("XXXXXX--TOKEN--XXXXX");
$webmastersService = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
$searchanalytics = $webmastersService->searchanalytics;
$request = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
$request->setStartDate($date);
$request->setEndDate($date);
$request->setDimensions(array('query'));
$request->setSearchType("web");
$qsearch = $searchanalytics->query($site, $request);
$rows = $qsearch->getRows();
```

Comment: This question seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572961/can-we-get-search-queries-details-from-google-webmaster-tools-api

Comment: Yes but there is no news on it. I hope i can get a response or a idea about this. Hae you any idea to share please ? @AnthonyMichaelCook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to

```
var_dump($rows);
```

and you'll get the idea.